# Dynamically update PHP generated elements after Ajax login

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I load content on the page (comments) via Ajax infinite scroll, and i use Ajax to login/out as well. Now on success login i want to update reply or like buttons depending on what that user has liked or disliked.

The simple method is not to use Ajax for login/out or to refresh the page anyway because i check what the user has liked/disliked with PHP and if the page dose not get refreshed those scripts do not fire again.

But if i refresh the page all the comments loaded are gone and the user needs to scroll again. One solution that i found is to use the `load()` method to refresh the divs with the scripts but I'm not sure that is the way to go. So basically how do i dynamically update elements on the page after Ajax login that are generated from PHP?

**Let me explain better:**

Let's say i have a `PHP` script that makes this check:

```
<?PHP
 $q = $db->query("SELECT who_liked FROM likes WHERE(com_liked = com_id AND who_liked = curent_user_id)"); //actual query uses prepared statments, this is for example
 $count = $q->rowCount();

 if($count > 0){
  echo "<style> #like_btn{background-color: green;} </style>";
 }
?>
```

So if the user is not logged in all the like/dislike buttons are gray. Now the login is done through Ajax, the user uses email/user_name and password to log in, a login sessions is started the user name, profile image are selected from the data base based on the user id and are displayed on the page/navBar. Now i need to make a check to see what that user has liked and so on, should i make this check in the Ajax response? should i use `load()` to refresh the like/dislikes of the comments and the script that check that? Should i put all the php scripts in the Ajax  response so they fire on success login?(witch i think is the way to go)

Ex:

```
    ,success: function(response) {// php scripts with the sql query for all the checks}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. You want to be able to keep the loaded comments that were already loaded after the user has logged in?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 yes and if i use ajax for logging in it works but i also want to update like/dislike buttons on the comments that the user liked or disliked

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to toggle the like/dislike buttons on AJAX request's response event and also want to identify liked and disliked buttons as well?

Comment: Will you also need to prevent double-Liking?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code,

Send a JSON encoded array on Login response,

```
<?PHP

 $q = $db->query("SELECT who_liked FROM likes WHERE(com_liked = com_id AND who_liked = curent_user_id)"); //actual query uses prepared statments, this is for example
 $count = $q->rowCount();

 if($count > 0){
  $response = ['success' => true];
 } else {
     $response = ['success' => true];
 }

 echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Use below CSS Script,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .like_btn{
        background-color: green;
    }

    .like_btn.liked {
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .like_btn.not-liked {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>
```

Add

> not-liked

use CSS class for not liked buttons as below on PHP page load,

```
<button class="like_btn not-liked">Like Button</button>
```

then you will be able to identify the liked/ disliked and not liked buttons.

Use

> liked

CSS class for liked buttons. So at any time you will be able to toggle the buttons using JavaScript.

```
<button class="like_btn liked">Like Button</button>
```

Finally the JQuery AJAX script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
        success:function(res) {
            // On Login Success
            if(res.success) {
                $('.like_btn').toggleClass('not-liked');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

*Feel free to leave comments, if you need any further clarifications.*